# JFrame & JDialog linking

Tags: java, swing

I'm using visual swing plugin for eclipse - this is the problem. In my when i click on button it should show dialog (or other jForm, but i've read that only one jfrom should be used by application) and hide first one which is not problem. But on second form i need same thing to happend, when button is clicked, i need first form to be shown back and second to be disposed.
Here's code (it's probably not greatly sorted, because i can't find my way around this visual swing)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Bilateral;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Constraints;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.GroupLayout;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Leading;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Trailing;


//VS4E -- DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE!
public class Intervencije extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JButton btnObjekat;
    private JButton btnEkipa;
    private JButton btnIzlaz;
    private JLabel jLabel0;
    private JPanel jPanel0;
    private JTextField txtBrojIntervencije;
    private JButton btnUcitaj;
    private JLabel jLabel3;
    private JPanel jPanel2;
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JLabel jLabel2;
    private JTextField txtDatum;
    private JTextField txtBroj;
    private JTextArea txtOpisi;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane0;
    private static final String PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";
    public Intervencije() {


        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(Intervencije.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle("Intervencije");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GroupLayout());
        add(getJPanel2(), new Constraints(new Leading(17, 422, 10, 10), new Leading(226, 71, 10, 10)));
        add(getJPanel0(), new Constraints(new Leading(12, 189, 12, 12), new Leading(18, 100, 10, 10)));
        add(getJPanel1(), new Constraints(new Leading(205, 227, 12, 12), new Leading(15, 202, 10, 10)));
        setSize(454, 334);
    }

    private JTextArea getTxtOpisi() {
        if (txtOpisi == null) {
            txtOpisi = new JTextArea();
            txtOpisi.setEditable(false);
            txtOpisi.setText("txtOpisi");
            txtOpisi.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 16));
            txtOpisi.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 16));
        }
        return txtOpisi;
    }

    private JScrollPane getJScrollPane0() {
        if (jScrollPane0 == null) {
            jScrollPane0 = new JScrollPane();
            jScrollPane0.setViewportView(getJTextArea0());
        }
        return jScrollPane0;
    }

    private JTextArea getJTextArea0() {
        if (txtOpisi == null) {
            txtOpisi = new JTextArea();
        }
        return txtOpisi;
    }

    private JTextField getJTextField2() {
        if (txtBroj == null) {
            txtBroj = new JTextField();
        }
        return txtBroj;
    }

    private JTextField getJTextField1() {
        if (txtDatum == null) {
            txtDatum = new JTextField();
        }
        return txtDatum;
    }




    private JLabel getJLabel2() {
        if (jLabel2 == null) {
            jLabel2 = new JLabel();
            jLabel2.setText("Opis");
        }
        return jLabel2;
    }

    private JLabel getJLabel1() {
        if (jLabel1 == null) {
            jLabel1 = new JLabel();
            jLabel1.setText("Datum i vreme");
        }
        return jLabel1;
    }

    private JPanel getJPanel2() {
        if (jPanel2 == null) {
            jPanel2 = new JPanel();
            jPanel2.setLayout(new GroupLayout());
            jPanel2.add(getJButton0(), new Constraints(new Leading(278, 10, 10), new Leading(35, 10, 10)));
            jPanel2.add(getJButton1(), new Constraints(new Leading(151, 10, 10), new Leading(35, 12, 12)));
            jPanel2.add(getJButton2(), new Constraints(new Leading(23, 10, 10), new Leading(35, 12, 12)));
            jPanel2.add(getJLabel3(), new Constraints(new Leading(184, 173, 10, 10), new Leading(9, 10, 10)));
        }
        return jPanel2;
    }

    private JLabel getJLabel3() {
        if (jLabel3 == null) {
            jLabel3 = new JLabel();
            jLabel3.setText("Vise informacija o");
        }
        return jLabel3;
    }

    private JButton getJButton3() {
        if (btnUcitaj == null) {
            btnUcitaj = new JButton();
            btnUcitaj.setText("Ucitaj");
        }
        return btnUcitaj;
    }

    private JPanel getJPanel0() {
        if (jPanel0 == null) {
            jPanel0 = new JPanel();
            jPanel0.setLayout(new GroupLayout());
            jPanel0.add(getJLabel0(), new Constraints(new Trailing(12, 12, 12), new Leading(3, 19, 10, 10)));
            jPanel0.add(getJButton3(), new Constraints(new Leading(21, 10, 10), new Leading(66, 12, 12)));
            jPanel0.add(getJTextField2(), new Constraints(new Leading(15, 72, 12, 12), new Leading(28, 12, 12)));
        }
        return jPanel0;
    }

    private JLabel getJLabel0() {
        if (jLabel0 == null) {
            jLabel0 = new JLabel();
            jLabel0.setText("Unesite redni broj intervencije");
        }
        return jLabel0;
    }

    private JButton getJButton2() {
        if (btnIzlaz == null) {
            btnIzlaz = new JButton();
            btnIzlaz.setText("Izlaz");
            btnIzlaz.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                    btnIzlazMouseMouseClicked(event);
                }
            });
        }
        return btnIzlaz;
    }

    private JButton getJButton1() {
        if (btnEkipa == null) {
            btnEkipa = new JButton();
            btnEkipa.setText("Ekipi");
            btnEkipa.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                    btnEkipaMouseMouseClicked(event);
                }
            });
        }
        return btnEkipa;
    }

    private JButton getJButton0() {
        if (btnObjekat == null) {
            btnObjekat = new JButton();
            btnObjekat.setText("Objektu");
        }
        return btnObjekat;
    }

    private JPanel getJPanel1() {
        if (jPanel1 == null) {
            jPanel1 = new JPanel();
            jPanel1.setLayout(new GroupLayout());
            jPanel1.add(getJLabel1(), new Constraints(new Leading(4, 135, 10, 10), new Leading(2, 29, 10, 10)));
            jPanel1.add(getJLabel2(), new Constraints(new Leading(13, 12, 12), new Leading(69, 57, 115)));
            jPanel1.add(getJTextField1(), new Constraints(new Leading(8, 105, 12, 12), new Leading(31, 12, 12)));
            jPanel1.add(getJScrollPane0(), new Constraints(new Bilateral(12, 12, 22), new Bilateral(99, 12, 22)));
        }
        return jPanel1;
    }

    public static void installLnF() {
        try {
            String lnfClassname = PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL;
            if (lnfClassname == null)
                lnfClassname = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfClassname);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot install " + PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL
                    + " on this platform:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main entry of the class.
     * Note: This class is only created so that you can easily preview the result at runtime.
     * It is not expected to be managed by the designer.
     * You can modify it as you like.
     */

    private void btnIzlazMouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        this.dispose();
    }

    public void btnEkipaMouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setVisible(false);
    Objekat o = new Objekat();
    o.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

here objekat o is class which either extends JFrame or JDialog

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Constraints;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.GroupLayout;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Leading;


//VS4E -- DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE!
public class Objekat extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton jButton0;
    private static final String PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";
    public Objekat(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Dialog parent, String title, boolean modal,
            GraphicsConfiguration arg) {
        super(parent, title, modal, arg);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Dialog parent, String title, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, title, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Dialog parent, String title) {
        super(parent, title);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Window parent, String title, ModalityType modalityType,
            GraphicsConfiguration arg) {
        super(parent, title, modalityType, arg);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Window parent, String title, ModalityType modalityType) {
        super(parent, title, modalityType);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Window parent, String title) {
        super(parent, title);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Window parent, ModalityType modalityType) {
        super(parent, modalityType);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Frame parent, String title) {
        super(parent, title);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Frame parent) {
        super(parent);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Dialog parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Dialog parent) {
        super(parent);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Frame parent, String title, boolean modal,
            GraphicsConfiguration arg) {
        super(parent, title, modal, arg);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Objekat(Frame parent, String title, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, title, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setForeground(Color.black);
        setLayout(new GroupLayout());
        add(getJButton0(), new Constraints(new Leading(237, 10, 10), new Leading(81, 10, 10)));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                mouseMouseClicked(event);
            }
        });
        setSize(428, 240);
    }

    private JButton getJButton0() {
        if (jButton0 == null) {
            jButton0 = new JButton();
            jButton0.setText("jButton0");
        }
        return jButton0;
    }

    private static void installLnF() {
        try {
            String lnfClassname = PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL;
            if (lnfClassname == null)
                lnfClassname = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfClassname);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot install " + PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL
                    + " on this platform:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main entry of the class.
     * Note: This class is only created so that you can easily preview the result at runtime.
     * It is not expected to be managed by the designer.
     * You can modify it as you like.
     */
//  public static void main(String[] args) {
//      installLnF();
//      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//          public void run() {
//              Objekat dialog = new Objekat();
//              dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(Objekat.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
//              dialog.setTitle("Objekat");
//              dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//              dialog.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(dialog.getSize());
//              dialog.pack();
//              dialog.setVisible(true);
//          }
//      });


    private void mouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        //this.getParent().setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

main

```
public class main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intervencije d = new Intervencije();
    d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //d.setVisible(true);
    //d.installLnF();
```

}

Comment: Use a modal form of the dialog & be done with it.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: 1+ to Andrew, and in your post, you may want to avoid using non-core classes, including the `org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.*` classes that are likely from Eclipse. Otherwise many of us won't be able to run your code.

Answer (score 2):

I looked through your code and see where you've created JButtons and all, but I don't see anywhere where ActionListeners have been added to *anything*. Without AcionListeners, JButtons won't invoke a behavior on button press. I think you need to fix this first, and also go through the basic Swing tutorials found on the Oracle Java tutorial site.

Comment: actually there is no actionlistener but in the code there is a mouse click event associated with the button so that'll work won't it?

Comment: @lucifer: Don't use MouseListeners with JButtons, as buttons are written to work specifically with Actions or ActionListeners, and are optimized for this. Instead always use an Action or ActionListener (with a few exceptions of course, none of which the OP has). For example, if you disable a JButton via `setEnabled(false)`, the ActionListener will behave appropriately and not initiate its action if the button is pressed. The MouseListener on the other hand will not respect this button state.

Comment: sir actually i always use actionlistener with a button coz i think they are optimised for that only actually they are meant to be used for being used with actionlistener but you said in previous comment that the code doesn't have an listener so i pointed out that it contains mouse listener.....
hey i've mastered simple swing where will i get advance swing tutorials can you name book or website?

Comment: @lucifer: Most Swing I've learned here and the standard Java Swing tutorials, which I'm sure you're familiar with. I also have gone through parts of the [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) book, one I highly recommend.

Comment: those MouseListeners were generater by visual swing himself (right click then action on mouse click or something like that)

Comment: @Nenad: using a visual designer without thinking about what it's doing and what you're supposed to be doing will only lead to trouble. Ditch the visual designer and read the tutorials if you want to learn to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Objekat` Class make an instance variable for `JFrame`, such as `private JFrame frame;`, now inside your constructor, where you getting an Object of the `JFrame` from the calling Class, get this reference, like `this.frame = frame;`, now modify your below given method to this form :

```
private void mouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) 
{
    frame.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
```

and modify your below method as described below :

```
public void btnEkipaMouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) 
{
    this.setVisible(false);
    Objekat o = new Objekat(this);
    o.setVisible(true);
}
```

Seems to me that's all you need to make this work. Since in your example, you not passing anything while creating an object of `Objekat` Class, hence I think no parent is assigned to it, hence your `actionPerformed(...)` method inside this Class, is not working as expected, try to make these changes, hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent tutorial for swing [Here](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial)

for opening any frame or dialog box when u click a button you have to create an object of that class in the action performed method and set its visiblity to true; in swing by default the visiblity is false for the frame which we've created....

instead of writing this

```
  public void btnEkipaMouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setVisible(false);
    Objekat o = new Objekat();
    o.setVisible(true);
```

code it'd be better to write actionlinstener like this

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ Objekat o = new Objekat(this);}
});
```

the above code is just the same as your code but it uses the default event listener rather than creating a new one.....

this is because if there is a available actionlistener available in the standard library it won't be praiseworthy to create custom handlers for a simple button click event...
if i am wrong please let me know...

if you want to dispose the second frame and show again the first frame then you can create reference of both frames in your class and assign the object to it while constructing the frame of the class that would five a dteady reference for both frames if you wanted to do any operations on any of them....

```
public class Intervencije extends JFrame {
Objekat prev, next;
}
```

the constructor will be like this

```
public Objekat (Objekat prev) {
   //the next frame is obviously the onn in which u r working
next = this;
prev.setVisible(true);
next.setVisible(false);//you can do whatever you want with prev and next
}
```

actionlistener will be like this

```
Objekat prev = this;
public void actionPerformed(Actionevent e){
    Objekat newFrame = new Objekat(prev)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to open a new frame or dialog then you must go with ActionListeners Event of JButton for JButton ActionListeners event see the  example on [ActionListener](http://tutorialdata.com/example/swing/JButtonActionExample.html)